# Powershell Json object manipulation

Tags: json, powershell

I am hitting a Rest API and collected a gnarly block of Json. I'm running convertfrom-json on that to get a powershell object which I would like to manipulate. Essentially I need to prune a number of field/values.

Its no issue to 'get' the fields I want to remove from the object as I can just drill down to the field and collect the value thats easy, where I am stuck is how to trim off that field from the posh object. Would appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Example:

```
$sample_json = @"
{
    "fields": {
        "field_one": 1,
        "field_two": 2,
        "field_three": "three",
        "field_four": "remove_me",
        "field_five": 5
    }
}
"@
Clear-Host 
$json_object = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $sample_json
$json_object
```

Gives:

```
fields                                                                            
------                                                                            
@{field_one=1; field_two=2; field_three=three; field_four=remove_me; field_five=5}
```

So the question is how can I remove "field_four" key, and it's value, from $json_object ? Apologies if this is crazy simple; I'm a bit out of touch with Powershell these last few years.

Comment: Please give us some code to test and explain some more what you try with some code parts.

Comment: ok, thanks. edited and added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove `"field_four"` with the `Remove` method from `PSObject.Properties`:

```
$json_object.fields.PSObject.Properties.Remove("field_four")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following statement

```
$json_object.fields.PSObject.Properties.Remove("field_four")
```